# Mypy: The `mypy` type for a Tensorflow TFRecords `Bytes` object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, binary, mypy

This is a strange one. So I am creating some Tensorflow TFRecords files to encode data. I wanted to check the `mypy` type of a single record file, which is encoded into a binary string.

Now, when I run the code below and check the `type()` of the string it indicated `<class 'bytes'>`. But when I use `mypy` `reveal_type()` it indicates `error: Revealed type is 'Any'`, so it looks like `mypy` is not recognizing a bytes type. Does this make sense? I don't really want to encode something as `Any` since that does not really help in catching the types of errors I want to catch with `mypy.`

Here is the sample code I used to generate the error. I took the code from a new tensorflow [TFRecords guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#writing_a_tfrecord_file_2), but the last few lines are my own.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import typing

def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


# the number of observations in the dataset
n_observations = int(1e4)

# boolean feature, encoded as False or True
feature0 = np.random.choice([False, True], n_observations)

# integer feature, random from 0 .. 4
feature1 = np.random.randint(0, 5, n_observations)

# string feature
strings = np.array([b'cat', b'dog', b'chicken', b'horse', b'goat'])
feature2 = strings[feature1]

# float feature, from a standard normal distribution
feature3 = np.random.randn(n_observations)


def serialize_example(feature0, feature1, feature2, feature3):
  """
  Creates a tf.Example message ready to be written to a file.
  """

  # Create a dictionary mapping the feature name to the tf.Example-compatible
  # data type.

  feature = {
      'feature0': _int64_feature(feature0),
      'feature1': _int64_feature(feature1),
      'feature2': _bytes_feature(feature2),
      'feature3': _float_feature(feature3),
  }

  # Create a Features message using tf.train.Example.

  example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
  return example_proto.SerializeToString()

serialized_example = serialize_example(False, 4, b'goat', 0.9876)
reveal_type(serialized_example)

print(type(serialized_example))
```